# How can I replace some string in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have CloudFormation template where i have one parameter passed from previous step  with value like this:

```
 "test1.example.org"

 "example.org"

 "org"
```

Now I want to basically remove the .org part from that parameter and get:

```
test1.example

example
```

There can be many subdomain as well like

```
test1.test2.test3.test4.example.org
```

I just need to remove .org from the end

Answer (score 26):

With a caveats you can achieve what you want - assuming that `.org` will appear only on the end of your string.

Here's a complete template `test.cfn.yaml` that shows this method working:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:
  Input:
    Type: String

Resources:
  DummyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:
  TheOutput:
    Value: !Join [ '', !Split [ '.org', !Ref Input ] ]
```

You can test this out with the AWS CLI by running:

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file test.cfn.yaml --stack-name test1 --parameter-overrides Input=apples.bananas.org`

The output of this stack will contain `apples.bananas`.

Within your script you can use `!Join [ '', !Split [ '.org', !Ref Input ] ]` to strip down your string as you wanted, replacing *Input* with the value you need changed.

Note that there is a `DummyBucket` in the stack as you need to have at least one resource for CloudFormation to deploy the script.

Comment: Nice answer. This is just what I needed.

Comment: @Miles You have provided a very useful template for testing YAML logic.  Very fast turnaround and you can push updates to the same stack to refine your logic.

Comment: Should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Please be aware, as @geoff.weatherall already stated, this only works when `.org` only appears at the end of your string.

This snippet would render `test.organic-fruit.org` as `test.anic-fruit`

Comment: @BillGale Your comment inspired me to see if it could be faster. S3 buckets seem to take ~20 seconds to create, whereas an SSM parameter takes 1-2 seconds (though requires you to set a Type and Value). I wonder if there's something that will take 1 second and require _no_ properties!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your query correctly, one way you could do it is you could use `Fn::Split` function to split the string by colon and use the array element that you want to use.

Comment: Ooh! That's a good idea! However, splitting on the dot would would product a _string list_. I'm not sure how it would be possible to then remove the last element before putting them back together with a Join. It _would_ be possible if the number of elements was always the same, since they could be directly referenced in the Join.

Answer (score 0):

There is no string manipulation capability in a CloudFormation template.

Worst case, you could create a **Lambda-backed Custom Resource** that can transform parameters.

Comment: If i make custom lambda and that return me that transformed paramater , how can i use that paramater in another part of cloudformation ?

Comment: Here's an example: [Walkthrough: Looking Up Amazon Machine Image IDs - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use any of the existing [Cloudformation method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html)s for this purpose. 
You can leverage the cloudformation template sample provided by AWS. Here is the example template [String manipulation](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions) which provides string transformation utility functions. You can easily extend the [python method](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions/string.yaml#L38-L61) to whatever operation you want.

CLI Command to create the stacks (after downloading them locally)

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name testString --template-body file://string.yaml  --profile your_profile --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:1234:stack/testString/ec34d8c0-9fc9-11e9-a0ed-0aa1af63e98c

aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name testStringExample --template-body file://string_example.yaml  --profile your_profile --capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:1234:stack/testStringExample/2047d720-9fca-11e9-ab63-12989ba5c57e
```

It creates a s3 bucket and adds various transformed tags. Command for vaidation.

```
aws s3api get-bucket-tagging --bucket teststringexample-s3bucket-1dgnx05oslymu --profile your_profile --output json

{
    "TagSet": [
        {
            "Value": "ring",
            "Key": "ShortenLeft"
        },
        {
            "Value": "his is a test input strin",
            "Key": "Strip"
        },
        {
            "Value": "THIS IS A TEST INPUT STRING",
            "Key": "Upper"
        },
        {
            "Value": "This_is_a_test_input_string",
            "Key": "Replace"
        },
        {
            "Value": "testStringExample",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
        },
        {
            "Value": "this is a test input string",
            "Key": "Lower"
        },
        {
            "Value": "This is a test input string",
            "Key": "Capitalize"
        },
        {
            "Value": "This Is A Test Input String",
            "Key": "Title"
        },
        {
            "Value": "S3Bucket",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
        },
        {
            "Value": "This",
            "Key": "ShortenRight"
        }
    ]
}
```